# Click event of Asp Link Button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 4 Link buttons in asp.net.
I have added same key handler function to all those buttons(using add handler).
Now i have to read that which button is clicked.
but i can not check their text property as the text is changing dynamically too.
How can i read which button is clicked.

Any different approach is also welcome.

Comment: You should add some code you tried, that will help us to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign any one unique value to differentiate `Link-button` 
you also can use different  `link-button` Command Argument or ID for different `link-button`

and use like

```
void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
       var senderss = (LinkButton)sender;
       var uniqueid = senderss.ID.ToString();
       var CommandArgs= senderss.CommandArgument.ToString();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on sender argument

```
void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
      var control =(LinkButton) sender;
      var id = control.Id;
      System.Console.Write(id);

}
```